# Linear systems, causality input-output

Tags: output, input, linear

I have been preparing for a midterm and my professor posted a sample midterm but no answers, i solved the question here and asked him if it made sense, and he said the answer will be fully correct if causality was taken into account, but i do not get what he means by that. [image: question + answer]

Comment: Casuality means that the value in present (`t`) can only depend on the values in the past, but not in the future (`t+1`).

Comment: so this means, I can discard the part of the solution that has (t+1)?

Comment: Not sure what it means in the context of your assignment. Maybe you just need to solve it for `U(t+1)` instead ? Then change variables.

Comment: okay, I understand I think, thank you